# How to get name of image with resourceid?

Tags: android

```
int igotit=getResources().getIdentifier(val, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Above statement returns `resourceid`. from that `resourceid` get the **imagename** that images are in `drawable` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for resource name from resource id. Use below api

```
   String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(resid);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
String res_name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

or

```
String res_name = getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```